# Counting elements once after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently passing one value from `search.php` to `filtering.php`. I am using `$_GET` to accomplish that. In the `filtering.php` page I have a table that auto filters based on a word typed in the input text box. I am passing the value in the URL like: `http://holaweblearning.co.nf/php_learning/filtering.php?key=Dragoo`. The value from the URL is taken and placed in the input text box and results are displayed.  I am able to run a function that counts the filtered results based on a word. The issue: the result count is off, it initially shows the correct value but after clicking on a result it adds `1`? [DEMO](http://holaweblearning.co.nf/php_learning/search1.php)

```
$(document).ready(function($) {

//Trigger key up on search box to show results for word
$('input#filter').trigger('keyup');

//Counts Results
function result_count(){
      var text =  $('.footable tbody tr:not(.footable-filtered)').length;
      $('h5#result_count').text('Number of Results: '+text);
    }
result_count();

//Run on page load
window.setInterval(result_count, 100);

});
```

Comment: Is that a typo the missing semi colon after the keyup trigger?

Comment: @MelanciaUK - Nope, it's just optional in JS.

Comment: It can be optional, but it's not recommended.

Comment: @MelanciaUK I forgot to place `;`, corrected now.

Comment: Works fine on Chrome.

Comment: @user3558931 click on the first result, count will change to +1

Comment: It works, but not to do what you're intending. The problem is clearly due to you adding particular HTML elements upon expanding an entry. Whatever you're adding is matched by your selector and thus increasing your length. It's accurately reporting the correct length.

Comment: Code_Ed_Student, see @sxnine's demo below my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click on a result, a new row was added like the following and since this type of row is **NOT BEING EXCLUDED** from the count, your count will go up by one.

```
<tr class="footable-row-detail"><td class="footable-row-detail-cell" colspan="3"><div class="footable-row-detail-inner"><div class="footable-row-detail-row"><div class="footable-row-detail-name">Job Title:</div><div class="footable-row-detail-value">Traffic Court Referee</div></div><div class="footable-row-detail-row"><div class="footable-row-detail-name">DOB:</div><div class="footable-row-detail-value">22 Jun 1972</div></div></div></td></tr>
```

Probably your function should be:

```
function result_count(){
      var text =  $('.footable tbody tr:not(.footable-filtered,.footable-row-detail)').length;
      $('h5#result_count').text('Number of Results: '+text);
}
```

So that it does not count this row.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Well explained! I will make the appropriate changes.